# Not sure if this is a recognized design pattern, need to improve it

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a base class which looks like this:

```
public abstract class MetadataBase : NgageControl, INamingContainer, IValidator
{
    public abstract Type DataType { get; }
    public string SerializedData { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I then have a generic class which extends the one above:

```
public abstract class MetadataBase<Tdata, Traw, Tsettings> : MetadataBase
    where Tdata : new()
    where Tsettings : new()
    where Traw : INgageData
{
     ....
}
```

I then have a set of classes based upon this one like this:

```
public class MetadataDateTime : MetadataBase<MetadataDateTimeData, NgageDateTime, MetadataDateTimeSettings>
{
public override Type DataType { get {return typeof(MetadataDateTimeData); } }
     ....
}
```

The reason for this approach is so that I can do things like this:

```
MetadataBase test = GetMetaData();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(test.DataType);
xs.Deserialize();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test.SerializedData));
_xs.Deserialize(ms);
ms.Dispose();
```

I could have gotten the MetadataDateTimeData type from the Type.GetGenericArguments method but I didn't want to start using reflection due to its slow performance, I'm not sure that I'm right but it seems that getting the type from an overridden property would be much faster.

This all works fine but it now seems that I may have to support getting the type statically. Currently I'm creating an instance of this class simply to get its Type in order to deserialize some data, this approach is going to really hurt performance so I was thinking of using attributes to specify the data class. The issue with this though is that you need to use reflection to read an attribute so I may as well just use the GetGenericArguments method.

What would you recommend doing?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Please note: I don't have all of the code in front of me so a lot of that is typed straight in to stack overflow, sorry if there are any typos!

Comment: Did you consider lazy initialization of your class? You still need to create a new instance to get the type but you'll create only what you use. As alternative why `GetMetaData()` instead of `GetMetaDataType()`? After all it knows the true type if it creates the instance...

Comment: Under what circumstances do you need to get the type statically?  Can you add that code?

Comment: If you just want the datatype you can use GetType(), this is not reflection and not slow.

Comment: I think GetGenericArguments method uses reflection too

Comment: After Bobson's comment I've had a look at it and I'm really just getting it statically to avoid duplicating some code used within the class. I can't put this code in to a shared external class because this whole thing is basically a plugin system. I've decided to just copy the code for now.